# How to generate a view from a controller in VS 2015 ASP.NET 5 MVC6

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am testing out the newest ASP.NET version in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. 
I have gotten to the point where I wanted to generate a View from a Controller.
In MVC 5, one of the ways this could be done was by right clicking the controller and selecting "Add View", in MVC 6 however I can't seem to find this option, nor any of the other options...

Does anyone know how to auto generate a view from the controller (with model class)? For example with the create template?

To simplify, I want the functionality of this VS 2013 screen: http://postimg.org/image/v5yvyf0nx/

Comment: Why don't you add a file manually in views folder...

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but I want it to auto-generate the view using a create template with a model class. (Because I really don't feel like writing all that stuff myself)

Comment: I think you mean you want to generate a view from a model or viewmodel not from a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not yet in VS2015 natively, however check out [aspnet/Scaffolding on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding), notably [Commandline scaffolding for ASP.NET vNext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/21/command-line-scaffolding-for-asp-net-vnext.aspx).

The docs are a year old, but the project does look like it is undergoing active development.

Comment: @A.R. it is after all still in beta :P

Answer (score 3):

You can add it : Views(folder) -> R click ->Add new item ->DNX -> Server-side -> MVC View smth (There are a lot templates).
Your previous action i think can be configurable in settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not really what I wanted, because all of these MVC View's are empty when created, there is no option to auto generate the code inside them.

Comment: To simplify, I want the functionality of this known and loved screen: http://postimg.org/image/v5yvyf0nx/

Comment: Add > New Item > MVC View Page bypasses the dialog that forces the developer to select a model and layout.  I do not use Add > View